# ionic eroor: 'libsass' bindings not found try reinstalling node-sass?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, gulp-sass, node-sass

I would like to run ionic application.
I use this commande`ionic serve`

I get this error :
Error 'libsass' bindings not found try reinstalling node-sass?
I've tried `npm rebuild node-sass` 
I've tried to uninstall node-sass and install glup-sass : `npm install --save-dev gulp-sass` but nothing works for me

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Did you try deleting `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` ?

Comment: yes I've try it but also doesn't work